# Translation errors in the french configuration list VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't know if this is the right place to report this, and if it isn't, can someone be so kind telling me where to do so?
This 'issue' is posted regarding some translation errors in the settings of VS Code. (french translation)
This is when the 'French Language Pack for Visual Studio Code' is installed.

Open VS Code
Click on 'Code' (macOS version) => 'Preferences' => 'Settings'
The settings are now open in the right pane of the screen.
Go to 'Gestion de l'éditeur' under 'Banc d'essai' and you'll see this:

[image: Gestion éditeur - fautes orthographe et contenu_aaa]

In the block 'Reveal if Open':
(second line) '...groupe éditeur actuellement *active*.' => must be 'actif'

In the block 'Show Tabs'
Contrôle si les ouverts éditeurs... => must be: Contrôle si les éditeurs ouverts ...

As suggested by Chris, I submitted this as a bug and as bug id #80076
This issue is 'solved'.

Comment: Probably better off reporting the bug on their github page: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues. Even better, if you can find the files in their source code, fix the typos and send them a pull request!

Comment: @ChrisTavares Hi Chris, thanks for your quick response. I'll see if I can find this in the code than. :-)